# how do you store an array within a new array using python

Tags: python, arrays

I am iterating through a list of numbers that are stored in an array, if they are less than 10, I want to store them in a new array. this is what I have tried so far.

```
num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
i []
for index in range(len(num)):
    if num[index] < 10:
            i = [num[index]]
            for index in range(len(i)):
                print i[index]
```

Comment: `i []` does what? have you googled this?

Answer (score 2):

```
num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
result = [x for x in num if x<10]
```

Comment: this works but why is there an x at the start of the for loop?

Comment: You should look into list comprehension in python.

Comment: That's a list comprehension.  If you wanted to square all the numbers in `x` you would say `[x**2 for x in num]`